# jQuery slideTo toggle starting faded

Tags: jquery, toggle, jquery-animate, fadeto

I want to use jQuery to toggle the opacity of an element between 0.3 and 1.0 on a button click. 
The trouble i am having is starting the element off with an opacity of 0.3 and then on the first click, making it fully visible with a 1.0 opacity. 
The code I have tried is below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Start faded to 0.3
    $(".fadingElement").fadeTo(0, 0.3);

    //When the trigger is clicked first, fade the relevant item back up to 1.0
    $("div.trigger").toggle(
        function(){ 
            $(this).parent().next().fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
        }, 
        function () {  
            $(this).parent().next().fadeTo('fast', 0.3);
        }
    );
});
```

When the "div.trigger" is clicked, it does not fade up, when clicked again, it fades a further 0.3! When clicked a third time, it fades to its starting 0.3.

How do i start the element at 0.3, and bring it back up to fully visible (1.0) on the first click? What is going on here?

Comment: It seems ok to me (tested in Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/FVjnX/

Comment: It also works with a test I made, just as with @James Allardice

Comment: Ahhh your jsfiddle test worked for me too! But my code is not. what on earth..

Comment: @Mikey - try copying and pasting the relevant parts of your actual code (all relevant HTML, CSS and JS) into a fiddle and see what happens. If it doesn't work, post the link to the fiddle here so we can take a look.

Comment: @James Allardice - Check this out, its having the problem described - http://jsfiddle.net/PLx5p/1/

Comment: @Mikey - Is this how it should behave: http://jsfiddle.net/PLx5p/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (based on the code in your fiddle) is that the element you actually want to fade is `<div class="student_notified">`, but your code is fading the parent of that `div` rather than the `div` itself.

You can use the `find` method to select the correct element within its parent:

```
$(this).parent().next().find(".student_notified").fadeTo('fast', 0.3);
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PLx5p/3/).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `.animate()` with `.css('opacity',value)` to achieve that behavior

Example:

```
$("div.trigger").toggle(
$(this).parent().next();
    $(this).parent().next().animate({opacity:1.0});
}, 
function () {  
    $(this).parent().next().animate({opacity:0.3});
   });
}
);
```

Comment: I have actually tried that with exactly the same result... Hmm, really wanting to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Firefox, same result with Safari